# Cannot generate mongoid config file in rails 4 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid4

I've created a rails 4 engine and I am now trying to get it to run with Mongoid instead of active record. I am following the [instructions on the official site](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) so I have added `s.add_dependency "mongoid", "~> 4.0.0"` to the gemspec file, thanI ran bundle install, no problem there, and after that I try to generate the mongoid config file by executing `rails g mongoid:config` from the engine's root folder but I get the following error:

```
gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/mongoid/config/config_generator.rb:16:in `app_name': undefined method `parent' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Additionally, I wanted to know if in the applications that will use this engine I also need to configure them to use Mongoid even though the only models they will use are part of the engine?

Comment: Why not use `gem "mongoid", ~> 4.0.0` in `Gemfile` but change `gemspec` file?

Comment: Because its an engine, not an app, and as far as I understand for engines you specify your gems in the gemspec file (like it is stated in the comments of those files).

Comment: did you figure this out @Julien

Comment: yeah you need to run the command from inside the dummy test app folder of your engine